# How to select elements from drop down by its values name

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to select a text value in-between label tag.
The HTML Code is below:

```
<label for="ctl11_ctl12_ctl17_divDropDown_ctl917">Vineet</label>
```

Çant use ElementById as the ids keep changing with addition of new entries inbetween the drop down.
So i am trying to select it by using the Name "Vineet"

Code Tried:
1-->HTMLDoc.getElementByName("Vineet").Click

2-->HTMLDoc.getElementByName("ctl111_ctl12_ctl17").value= "Vineet" 
note:- i have to read and select the values in dropdown.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You'll need to do something like `getElementsByTagName("SELECT")(index)` where you'll need to loop the to find the index possibly from the resultant collection.  Can you post some of the HTML?

Comment: Hi Nathan_Sav i have added html code for label tag and please note values which iam looking to select is in dropdown and if i pass index no then if in future other elements are added then index no will also change.